# Cannot set icons for apps after deleting the icons cache

Tags: icon

I ran these commands as suggested in another thread:

```
sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.dock.iconcache -exec rm {} \;
sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.iconservices -exec rm -rf {} \;
sudo rm -rf /Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store
```

After that, I am trying to change app icons by going to Get Info, selecting the icon, and pasting an image in the selection. However, instead of the icon, I get a generic file icon like below:

[image]

How can I revert those commands?

Comment: RE: "How can I revert those commands?" -- You **cannot** as `sudo rm -rf` on the target is final, it's gone for good! To change an icon, have a look at: [Change icons for files or folders on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-icons-for-files-or-folders-on-mac-mchlp2313/mac)

Comment: @user3439894 I have tried exactly what your linked article says but what I get is the generic icon as shown on my screenshot in my question. That generic icon is set as the app icon. The same happens with files and folders. The actual picture is not shown.

Comment: 1. What version of **macOS** are you running? 2. Have you rebooted since deleing the _iconcache_ and other _files_? 3. Ary you opening the _image_ in an _application_ to then copy it to the _clipboard_? What _application_ are you copying the images in? 4. If on **macOS Big Sur**, you cannot use that procedure in the **Apple** support document on any of the _preinstalled applications_ as they reside on a _cryptographically  signed read-only volume_.